# PHP query between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set a table up to display out of date tests. So, I have a test that is dated `28/01/2014` and the next test is due on `28/01/2015`. As of today's date, this is out of date.

My query looks like the following:

```
$expiry = date("Y-m-d");
$queryout = "SELECT appliances.*, tests.* FROM (appliances LEFT JOIN tests  
             ON appliances.ID = tests.Appliance) WHERE Cli_ID = '$useractiveid' 
             AND `Next Test Due` BETWEEN `Date Tested` AND  '" . $expiry . "'";
```

I want the query to find tests that are out of date where the `Next Test Due` is out of date.

Comment: I'm confused on what you're asking. You should also format your code to be multiple lines so it is easier to read.

Comment: The CURDATE() function returns todays date - compare that to the next test due date. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Comment: Note that dates in SQL adhere to a specific format.

Comment: `where Next Test Due <  '" . $expiry . "'`

Comment: @FutbolFan thanks, this worked a treat.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help! :) Please feel free to mark the answer below as accepted as it will help others know this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer based on my comments:

```
$expiry = date("Y-m-d");
$queryout = "SELECT appliances.*, tests.* FROM (appliances LEFT JOIN tests  
             ON appliances.ID = tests.Appliance) WHERE Cli_ID = '$useractiveid' 
             AND where Next Test Due < '" . $expiry . "'";
```